# Add URL to slider with Custom Field in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, slider

I'm trying to add a url to each slide, via a custom field I created.

This was already in the code:

```
            <img src="<?php echo bfi_timthumber($largeImage, 980, (int)$sliderHeight)?>" width="980" height="<?php echo $sliderHeight ?>" title="#nivocaption<?php echo $i?>"/>
```

So I thought if I created the custom field I could just wrap it in this:

```
 <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slide_url', true); ?>"> ABOVE CODE HERE </a>
```

But unfortunately that isn't working. Any thoughts to why?

Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/yNzk8izb

Comment: Whenever I put the same code (not wrapped in html) above the html/php part.. it displays it twice. http://cl.ly/3g051Z443n1Z1e1b2428

Answer (score 0):

well - I do not know your theme / plugin , but the 
$lardeImage parameter is the one you probably need to use .
Wraping it like you did will obviously make it double, because you are not over riding the code, you just add to it .

try :

```
$largeImage = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slide_url', true);
```

and then the code .

Note :
(it might not work, because like i said - i do not know the plugin / theme function - but the $LargeImage parameter name sugests it needs to take only the "FULL" image size .. )

But try it anyhow .

Comment: It just printed this: http://cl.ly/0Y140k2N1q003W2z2S1g - it's some pre-made theme with Nivo slider built in. Not Nivo the plugin, but rather the free version and its deeply embedded into the theme with limited options.